# Accessing variables from another module

Tags: python, variables, module

Although I received two answers to my problem (for which I am grateful), they do not answer my problem, or I am not able understand the answers.
So here is a more detailed explanation of what I am trying to do:
I have two modules a.py and b.py

```
#a.py

from zzzz import *

Bob.Name = 'Jack'
Bob.Age = 65

print(Bob.Name, Bob.Gender,Bob.Age)


# b.py
class Record(object): 
    Name = ''
    Gender = '' 
    Age = ''
    
Line = 'Bob=Male=40'   ### This what I would like to come from a.py
M = Line.split('=')   

exec(M[0] + ' = ' + 'Record()')
exec(M[0] + '.' + 'Name'   + ' = ' + "'" + M[0] + "'")
exec(M[0] + '.' + 'Gender' + ' = ' + "'" + M[1] + "'")
exec(M[0] + '.' + 'Age'    + ' = ' + "'" + M[2] + "'")

print(Bob.Name, Bob.Gender, Bob.Age)
```

The results that I'm getting when I run a.py is:

```
Bob Male 40
Jack Male 65
```

Which is fine, it works exactly as I wanted it.

**The only thing I would like to do is to declare "Line" in a.py** which then will be used in b.py as the input.

Basically I would like to create an object in another module where input comes from the calling module, and will be able to use "dot notation" in the calling module.

Answer (score 0):

There's a problem with the current setup - in **b.py**, you don't do any importing; so you can't access any variables defined elsewhere.

Here's an approach you can try instead. In **a.py**:

```
class Dessert:
    def __init__(self, kind):
        self.kind = kind

    def get_menu(self):
        print('I am a:', self.kind)
```

And in **b.py**:

```
from a import Dessert
c = Dessert('cookie')
d = Dessert('donut')
c.get_menu()
d.get_menu()
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly this should do it:

```
#a.py

Line = 'Bob=Male=40'

# b.py
from a import Line # assuming a.py and b.py are in the same directory

...
```